# Flutter Fresh Project Always Getting error at all Flutter Channel

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart

I can't simply run any flutter application on my Windows 10 machine. Even the fresh one without any changes (example app).

What I do is just simply

`Flutter create testing12`
`cd testing12`

and then I run the app with the command of:

`Flutter Run`

I've already tried different channels of flutter namely stable, beta, and master. But it didn't help.

Heres my Flutter Doctor -v output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-4.0.pre.19, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-4.0.pre.19 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 7c22057f60 (46 minutes ago), 2020-06-02 21:08:03 -0400
    • Engine revision 6589dcb2d4
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-13.0.dev 3d53df52af)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.11.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • RMX1851 • 5f405b50 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
```

And heres the error that I'm trying to solve.

```
C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12>flutter run  --verbose
[   +9 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +63 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 7c22057f60e9b758b98a8d3a55ce8af949f8b9e1
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[ +178 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[   +3 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git describe --match *.*.*-*.*.pre --first-parent --long --tags
[  +41 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match *.*.*-*.*.pre --first-parent --long --tags
[   +1 ms] 1.19.0-3.0.pre-19-g7c22057f6
[   +7 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +34 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/master
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +33 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +102 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +39 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] master
[  +46 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +23 ms] executing: C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +38 ms] List of devices attached
           5f405b50               device product:RMX1851 model:RMX1851 device:RMX1851 transport_id:2
[   +6 ms] C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5f405b50 shell getprop
[ +102 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +168 ms] Generating C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +22 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[  +47 ms] Starting incremental build...
[   +3 ms] Initializing file store
[  +10 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +7 ms] complete
[   +5 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1851 in debug mode...
[   +5 ms] C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill
C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.1d484e7d\flutter_tool.3dfaa701\app.dill --packages .packages -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme
org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +25 ms] executing: C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5f405b50 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +101 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5f405b50 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[   +1 ms] --------- beginning of main
           06-03 08:56:16.336 D/        ( 1225): thermal_monitor gpu0-usr: open fail -1
[  +14 ms] <- compile package:testing12/main.dart
[   +9 ms] executing: C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +29 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.1-6435776
           Installed as C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\GL63\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +25 ms] Building APK
[  +23 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +3 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +3 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +1 ms] C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[   +9 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[  +87 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[   +1 ms] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +5 ms] executing: [C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\android/] C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64
-Ptarget=C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+1140 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[+16390 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[   +2 ms] [  +10 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] [  +60 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] [        ] 7c22057f60e9b758b98a8d3a55ce8af949f8b9e1
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --contains HEAD
[        ] [ +186 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --contains HEAD
[        ] [   +1 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git describe --match *.*.*-*.*.pre --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] [  +40 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match *.*.*-*.*.pre --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] [        ] 1.19.0-3.0.pre-19-g7c22057f6
[   +1 ms] [  +32 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +2 ms] [  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] [        ] origin/master
[   +1 ms] [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] [  +38 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[   +1 ms] [  +69 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] [  +32 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] [        ] master
[   +2 ms] [  +27 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [   +9 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +60 ms] Initializing file store
[        ] [  +12 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[        ] [   +6 ms] kernel_snapshot: Starting due to {}
[        ] [  +26 ms] C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform
--packages C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\.packages --output-dill C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\.dart_tool\flutter_build\7ff0e401bc39c516128145121fb8d783\app.dill --depfile
C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\.dart_tool\flutter_build\7ff0e401bc39c516128145121fb8d783\kernel_snapshot.d package:testing12/main.dart
[+5439 ms] [+5622 ms] kernel_snapshot: Complete
[ +699 ms] [ +648 ms] debug_android_application: Starting due to {}
[ +101 ms] [ +149 ms] debug_android_application: Complete
[ +598 ms] [ +529 ms] Persisting file store
[   +1 ms] [  +14 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [  +15 ms] build succeeded.
[   +1 ms] [  +14 ms] "flutter assemble" took 7,123ms.
[ +205 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[  +11 ms] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[  +96 ms] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
[   +3 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[   +6 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[  +26 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[  +12 ms] > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
[  +17 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[   +3 ms] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[ +210 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[   +3 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[  +93 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +297 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[  +28 ms] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[+1276 ms] > Task :app:processDebugManifest
[ +208 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources
[ +988 ms] > Task :app:processDebugResources
[+2106 ms] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
[ +110 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[+46779 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
[   +4 ms] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
[+1294 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileDebugSources
[ +297 ms] > Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
[   +2 ms] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
[ +896 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
[   +3 ms] Unable to strip library 'C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\debug\out\lib\x86\libflutter.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'.
Packaging it as is.
[ +396 ms] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
[   +3 ms] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
[   +1 ms] Unable to strip library 'C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\debug\out\lib\x86_64\libflutter.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'.
Packaging it as is.
[   +2 ms] Unable to strip library 'C:\Users\GL63\Documents\Coding\flutter\testing12\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\debug\out\lib\arm64-v8a\libflutter.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI
'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
[ +691 ms] > Task :app:mergeDexDebug
[+2998 ms] > Task :app:packageDebug
[ +260 ms] > Task :app:assembleDebug
[   +2 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
[   +1 ms] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[   +1 ms] See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[   +1 ms] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 23s
[   +1 ms] 31 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 11 up-to-date
[  +12 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 83.9s)
[   +7 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 84,652ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:569:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:797:18)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
#11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
#19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
#20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
#28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

I've tried to reinstall Android Studio, reinstall Flutter, trying different SDK version, but I can't figure this out, how can this happens on my machine. The fresh app is work well when I run it on the web version, but I can't run it on my Android, I try to build the apk with this command

`Flutter build apk`

and it getting the same error as I mentioned before. I really need help with this one, I've spent more than 20 hours to solve this problem but still can't figure this out.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: there not error i found in here??

Comment: ya, i have no idea, but i cant run this on my android nor i cant build the apk,,

Comment: If i'm not use `--verbose` command, then it stop with only this message `Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1`.

Comment: what's the rest of errors?

Comment: there are no other explanation for the error,, thats why its so hard to solve,, is there a way to tell the error other than using --verbose ? i mentioned all of the output on the question above.. and thats all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who maybe have the problem, what i do to solve this is **Factory Reset my Windows.**
I think the problem is on the operating system.